# How to get Textbox background color in TestStack.White

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, white-framework

I am using TestStack.White for automation testing of my WPF code. I am trying to get the background color of one of my textbox's. I tried to use NativeWindow to get the background color but it is not giving me the currect color code. Is there anything wrong in my code or Is there any other way I can do that?

Application application = null;
            Window window = null;
            application =
                Application.Launch(
                    @"C:\New folder\WPFTRaining\Automation.TimelineUI\Automation.TimelineUI\bin\Debug\Automation.TimelineUI.exe");

```
        var windows = application.GetWindows();
        window = windows.Find(x => x.Id == "Form1");


        TextBox age = window.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("TextBoxAGE"));
        age.Enter("90");

        Button saveButton = window.Get<Button>("SaveButton");
        saveButton.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        var nativeWindow = new NativeWindow(new IntPtr(window.Get<TextBox>("TextBoxAGE").AutomationElement.Current.NativeWindowHandle));
        Assert.AreEqual(nativeWindow.BackgroundColor,"#FF0000");
```

Comment: Are you instantiating a new instance of the window on the bottom line?

Comment: Its the new instance of NativeWindow

Comment: Is that a new instance of the currently open window or another window.